# Docker compose detached mode not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

> Q. How to run docker-compose in detach mode

I am trying to run docker-compose in detach mode but it ***will exits after just it's run***, but I am able run same image in detach mode using 'docker run' command.

- Run image using 'docker run' command   **(works in detach mode)**

  ```
  docker run -itd ubuntu:16.04
  ```

  below is output of 'docker ps -a' command

  ```
  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
  d84edc987359        ubuntu:16.04        "/bin/bash"         4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds                                   romantic_albattani
  ```
- Run same image using 'docker-compose up -d' command **(didn't work in detach mode)**

  below is my docker-compose.yml file

  ```
  version: '3'
  services:
  ubuntu:
      image: ubuntu:16.04
  ```

  'docker-compose ps' command output

  ```
           Name              Command    State    Ports 
  ----------------------------------------------------
  composetesting_ubuntu_1   /bin/bash   Exit 0
  ```

> Update: When using tty: true parameter in docker-compose.yml file as below

```
version: '3'
services:
ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    tty: true
```

then console will not execute any command, like if I type 'ls -l' command console will not responding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had to add tty: true to my docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '2'
    services: 
      ubuntu:
        image: ubuntu:16.04
        tty: true
```

Docker version 1.12.5, build 7392c3b

docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35

Comment: yes, it works but how. here 'tty:true' is also not a part of documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @AnandSuthar That link goes to compose version 3 format - note this example is version 2; that doc does include `tty`. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/

Comment: @AnandSuthar And to answer your question, `tty: true` just emulates a tty, the same thing `docker run -t` does (as used in your example in the question). When a tty is present, the shell will stay running if in detached mode; without a tty, it will find nothing else to do and exit.

Comment: but after attaching to container I am not able to execute any command like "ls -l". Whit will not show any result :(

Answer (score 3):

Above @fewtile42's answer is correct respect to my question. But only using 'tty: true' parameter user will not able to execute any command, so if one also want to execute or interact with console one should also use **'stdin_open: true'** parameter.

```
version: '2'
services: 
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    tty: true 
    stdin_open: true
```